# Structuring model class in appengine (since tuple is NOT available)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, schema

I am designing software for production management. My app allows my users to do the following:

1. Users can create a "schedule". A schedule specifies what types of vegetable produces needs to be ready at a particular date.
2. each vegetable has different durations for propagation, transplanting and harvesting.
3. My software works backwards and figures out what needs to be done on which date etc.

I am having trouble designing the data structure for a Schedule.

I have the following now:

```
class Produce(db.Model):
  crop = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  duration_sow = db.IntegerProperty()
  duration_transplant = db.IntegerProperty()
  duration_storage = db.IntegerProperty()
```

and a schedule looks something like this in JSON:

```
a_schedule = { 
  "crops": [ {"produce": Key(123), "quantity", 15}, {"produce": Key(234), "quantity", 16} ], 
  "created_by": ....
}
```

Since Appengine datastore does not support tuples, I am not really sure of how I can store the "crops" attribute in my model.

**OPTION 1**

I've considered using two arrays,

```
crops_key = [ Key(123), Key(234), .. ]
quantity = [ 15, 16, ... ]
```

but then deleting and modification might get a little tricky. This works, but I've encountered this pattern quite frequently and I just want to see what the experts out there have to recommend.

I am using python if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ListProperty in db.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty

Which allows you to store multiple keys.
I maintain two list properties in sync in an old project based on db.

I notice you are using db, if you don't have a significant code base in place, consider moving to ndb.  ndb has ab better model for storing this data. Have a read up on StructuredProperties in ndb.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

Comment: Yeah I am reading the NDB now. I quite like StructuredProperties